# CSS on hover effect on a <td> does not wok properly if <td> has multiple <div>s inside it

Tags: css, background, html-table, hover, highlight

I have a table column with multiple divs inside it to fit in an icon, title and description text. Also, on mouse over, I need to provide a highlight /overlay effect that highlights all of the column including the divs image, title and description text.

Here is the HTML

```
 <td>
   <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid red">left</div>
    <div style="display:inline-block">
    <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid blue">top left</div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid green">top right</div>
    <div>bottom </div>  
   </div>
 </td>
```

When I use a simple CSS effect to change the background of the column as below, the effect shows up only on individual divs but not the entire table column. I want that if any of the divs get a mouse over, all of the column should be highlighted.

CSS code

```
#MyTable td :hover {
background: #cccccc;
}
```

Comment: remove the space as this: #MyTable td:hover  ;)

Comment: The space between `td :hover` means that the style will be applied to descendants of `td`, i.e. all the `<div>` elements, instead of `td:hover` which adds the dynamic pseudo-class to the `td` itself

Comment: Aah, @andyb that was the explanation I was looking for. Thank you so much. Thanks !

Comment: Happy to help clarify the _why_, since none of the answers did :-)

Comment: On a slightly related topic - my <td> has some padding. I don't want to highlight the padding, just the content (the divs) insides the <td> . Is there a way ? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you have an extra space before `:hover` : try with

```
#MyTable td:hover { 
   background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#MyTable td:hover {
  background: #cccccc;
}
```

i think problem is you should use ":" right after "td"

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to delete the space before hover

```
#MyTable td:hover {
background: #cccccc;
}
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wooder89/eUCG5/